# Reduce spacing of curve CV to make it fit in one page

Tags: cv

I tried the command `\rubricafterspace`. But somehow its showing errors. Also is there any way to shift the heading part few pts above.

```
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{EB Garamond}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi



\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

% You can change the "ribbon" item markers here

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
\input{publications}

\makerubric{skills}
\makerubric{misc}

\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are countless ways of making a resume, can you show us the code of yours? Without it your question is hopeless to answer I fear. (Remove all personal info before posting it here though.)

Comment: Guess this is coming from https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv#.V-DxE7Psxz0, if it is, please edit the url to the question. (license).